# Using nohup to send process to the background

Tags: php, ubuntu, nohup

I have this script in php

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
    require ('config.php');
    require ('db_class.php');
    $db = new MySQLDatabase;

$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("27k.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        //echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
           // echo $data[$c] . '<br/>';

    $jsonString = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $decoded = json_decode($jsonString, true);

    $phone = $data[$c];
    $msg = 'Bulk message';
    $time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $sql="insert into UNITED.dbo.ozekimessageout (sender,receiver,msg,msgtype,status,flag,scheduledtime) 
                                  values ('NOW SMS','".$phone."','".$msg."','SMS:TEXT','Send','1','".$time."')";
    $db->query($sql);
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

?>
```

I named the script `csv.php` and sent this to process in the background with `nohup php csv.php &`.

The csv file i am reading has 10,000 records. Will the script stop inserting in the database after 10,000 records or will it continue executing even after 10,000 records are inserted?.

Answer (score 0):

Script will stop when its process finish working.

e.g. exit, program end or error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you be having more detail collaborating this,maybe some docs.